# Is it possible to create a program that retrieve photos' tagged names?

Tags: .net, facebook

I think I should first mention that I have never worked with anything that has to do with Facebook before.
I should also mention that I'm using .NET.

My question is: Is it possible to access the name tags of photos in Facebook (given a specific member's name) ?

What are some good resources on the subject (starting with the basics..)?
Does it involve Facebook-API?

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you mean retrieve tags for the specific photo or do a search for all photos that are tagged with specific name?

Comment: Actually both are relevant.. Help on any of these will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api). In order to use it you probably would need to [register a facebook app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) first and then request some [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) from your users through [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process to be able to access their private data.

To get tags for a specific photo you would use the following graph api path:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<photo_id>?access_token=...
```

It should return a JSON object that contains `tags` array with a list of users tagged in this picture, as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo). To access photos from a user you probably would need to request `user_photos` extended permissions (unless it is you or your friend).

To get photos the user has been tagged in, you can use this graph url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/photos?access_token=...
```

You would need `user_photo_video_tags` and `user_photos` permission for that, as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).

I don't know anything about .NET side of things, sorry.

I know this all is a bit overwhelming to grasp right away :) I think you need to read through the docs first, register an app, find .NET API library and try to make an authorization process. After that Graph API is pretty easy to understand.

Comment: I would have +10 this answer if I could.. That's one of the best answers I've ever got here..  Thanks.